# An integral has infinite number of singularities

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I don't know how to evaluate this integral.

$$\int _{0}^{\infty} \frac {x \tan x \cos (\tan^2 x)}{x^2+1}dx$$

Comment: Are you sure it is convergent?

Comment: each portion of the integral between singularities of the tangent are conditionally convergent

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  How can we prove each portion of the integral between singularities are conditionally convergent ?

Comment: And at each singularity $\frac{k\pi}{2}$ (odd $k$) the left-right behaviours of the function are in anti-phase, so the integral values are decreasing as $O(\frac{1}{k^2})$. Hmm... it seems to be convergent.

Comment: @mayhem The factor $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ has no effect on convergence at each singularity. Change the variable $t=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$ to get $\tan x\cos(\tan^2x)\,dx=\frac12\frac{\cos(t-1)}{t}\,dt$. The latter integral is conditionally convergent at $+\infty$.

Comment: When you're ready to show some work, or add some thoughts, or motivation, etc., within your question posts, you'll risk 1) not getting any answers, 2) your question being closed, perhaps deleted.